# how to call the stored procedure multiple times in a single page in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

```
DELIMITER //;
CREATE PROCEDURE count_nodes (IN userid INT, IN amount INT)
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE temp (id INT PRIMARY KEY, c_date DATETIME, amount INT, userid VARCHAR(100), id_left VARCHAR(100), id_right VARCHAR(100), leftcount INT, rightcount INT, side INT);
INSERT INTO temp SELECT *, 0 FROM bin WHERE bin.userid = userid;
REPEAT
    INSERT IGNORE INTO temp
    SELECT bin.*, CASE WHEN bin.userid = temp.id_left THEN 1 ELSE 2 END FROM bin JOIN temp ON bin.userid IN (temp.id_left, temp.id_right);
UNTIL NOT ROW_COUNT() END REPEAT;
SELECT SUM(side=1) left_childs, SUM(side=2) right_childs FROM temp WHERE temp.`amount` = amount;
DROP TABLE temp;
END
```

I'm having this stored procedure and I wanna display the outputs in a html table using php

I wanna call this procedure multiple times in a single php page
What I've tried is ...

```
$qry = "CALL count_nodes_test('user_1',3000)";

   if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $qry)) 
                  {
                    foreach ($result as $row ) 
                    {
                          $left_childs=$row['left_childs'];
                          $right_childs=$row['right_childs'];
                          
                          
                              $total = $left_childs + $right_childs;
                         
?>
      <th scope="row"><?php echo number_format($total); ?></th>
     
   $qry = "CALL count_nodes_test('user_2',3000)";

   if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $qry)) 
                  {
                    foreach ($result as $row ) 
                    {
                          $left_childs=$row['left_childs'];
                          $right_childs=$row['right_childs'];
                          
                          
                              $total = $left_childs + $right_childs;
                         
?>
      <th scope="row"><?php echo number_format($total); ?></th>
```

The problem is the first call is working and the second one is not working... Help me in this..

Comment: Do you get any errors (assuming error reporting is enabled)?

Comment: Thank you for your response !!.. No am not getting any errors @NigelRen

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to call sql stored procedure multiple times in a single page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63722878/how-to-call-sql-stored-procedure-multiple-times-in-a-single-page)