# how to call sql stored procedure multiple times in a single page

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, call

I am having a stored procedure `count_nodes(id,amount)` in mysql and i wanna call this procedure in php page with 4 different parameters in a single page. Actually I can't do that

I'm trying to call this procedure as

```
$qry = "CALL count_nodes_test('$userid',1500)";
```

and the other query is

```
$qry = "CALL count_nodes_test('$userid',3000)";
```

the problem is , am getting correct output for the first query and the 2nd query is not working without any error

Comment: It would be helpful if you would show the error is and also show how you call the procedure.

Comment: Create additional procedure which calls your procedute twice (or more) and call it.

Comment: @Akina Or write a new SP with receive more amounts as argument.

Comment: Yeah I have tried that too.. can't even call two procedures in a single page. @Akina

Comment: *can't even call two procedures in a single page.* You will call ONE procedure. And this one procedure will call all procedures you need one-by-one.

Comment: @Akina How can I give parameters to all the SP from front end?

Comment: `CREATE main_proc (IN param) BEGIN CALL proc1(param); CALL proc2(param); END`